# How can I integrate rational functions with denominator with just quadratics as factors?

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

I am told about integration by partial fraction method.I usually guess to decompose a fraction into partial fractions and then I solve the constants.In this problem: $$\int\frac{x^2+2x+6}{(x^2+5x+7)(x^2+6x+7)}$$ I tried to form its partial fraction but I wasn't able to.

Also note that this is an imaginary problem to satisfy my concepts by giving counterpositive statements as equation.My book says:

> The rational functions which we shall consider here for integration purposes will be those whose denominators can be factorised into **linear and quadratic factors**.It is **always possible** to write the integrand as a sum of simpler rational functions by a method called partial fraction decomposition method.After this, the integration can be carried out easily using the already known methods.

Comment: Partial fractions is the way to go on this, can you show your work so that we can help you find where you got stuck?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I usually use 3 constants unlike the answer so I guess I wasn't able to find out the answer because of it.

Comment: Whenever you do partial fractions, your numerators should be one degree lower than your denominators (except in the case of powers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second factor in the denominator factors into $(x-r_1) (x- r_2)$, where the $r$s are the roots of the quadratic, 
$$
\frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{36-28}}{2}= \frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2}=
-3 \pm \sqrt{2}
$$
So your partial fraction decomp looks like
$$
\frac{Ax + B}{x^2 + 5x + 7} + \frac{C}{x-r_1} + \frac{D}{x - r_2}
$$
You just have to find the right $A, B, C, D$.